# Display iframe when user wants to close the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to display an iframe when a user wants to close my web page. I tried to do that using jQuery (I'm really not good in jQuery), but I cannot even display a message before the browser's tab is closed. I tried:

```
<script>
   $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
return "Do you really want to leave now?";
});
</script>
```

also tried

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
                return '....';
     }); 
</script>
```

It is possible that I have missed something basic...

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Are you sure you're importing jQuery into the page?

Comment: Also, you use the term "iframe", but a "beforeunload" handler results in a popup, and that is not at all the same thing as an "iframe".

Comment: ahh,is this why I keep getting a pop up "Are you sure you want to leave"?Yes, I want an iframe,not a popup...

Comment: Yes,I have imported jQuery,there are no errors,just,when I'm lucky enough - the popup

Comment: I'm afraid that the popup is the best you can do. Browsers restrict your ability to do more complicated things when a user wants to close the tab or navigate away to a new URL.

Comment: I believe here works in a similar way to what I desire http://reset-password-pro.com (sometimes)

Answer (score 1):

Display iframe code :

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        $("#dialog").load("iframecontent.htm").dialog({dialogoptions});
    };
```

Display messsage :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Do you really want to close?";
};
```

**OR**

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var msg= "\o/";
  (e || window.event).returnValue = msg;
  return msg;                   
});
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        $(".dialog").load("test2.htm").dialog({dialogoptions});
    };
});</script>
</head>
<body><div class="dialog"></div></body>
</html>   This I tried first, but nothing happened, then I tried $( document ).ready(function() {
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
     return "Do you really want to close?";
 };
}); It produced: "This page is asking you to confirm ..."

Comment: Yes, but no iframe was displayed, the page was closed right away. Sorry for the hardly readable code above...

Comment: Ah, I see, but this way don't I need to include the source you reference and modify it to have this $( "#dialog" ).